Use Presenter View on iPad when mirroring to another monitor
Using my iPad, I want to be able to project something on an external screen while having presenter notes show on my iPad. The Microsoft PowerPoint iPadOS app does this.
What do I need to do in order to accomplish the same thing?
I used my iPad and initiated screen mirroring with my web app but I am unable to show a Presenter View the same way the Microsoft PowerPoint iPadOS app does. I want to develop my web app to have the same functionality so that a presenter view appears on my iPad and the main slide appears on the external screen.
